# RLMException when save an object in a background thread

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

When saving an object asynchronously in the background, I get **RLMException: 'Can not add objects from a different Realm'**. However, the same save works fine if remove the async code.

This object has a relationship to an existing object. For example:

```
class Person: Object {
  name: String
  school: School
}

class School: Object {
  name: String
}

let person = new Person()
person.name = "John"
person.school = school // Existing object selected from a dropdown.

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm!

        try realm.write {
            realm.add(person, update: true)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Success!
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Error!
        }
    }
}
```

This code results in a crash. However if I remove the DispatchQueye.global().async, everything works fine. Is there some threading issue I'm running into?

Note: the `school` object is pre-existing, and selected from a `Results<School>` collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Realm `Object` instances can't be moved between threads once they've been saved to Realm. Since `school` would be an object that was instantiated on the main thread, you're creating a conflict by attaching it to an un-persisted object and moving the lot to a background thread.

To fix this, you'll need to make a background version of the `school` object using [Realm's thread reference feature](https://realm.io/news/obj-c-swift-2-2-thread-safe-reference-sort-properties-relationships/).

Also, unless you have a specific reason for creating `Person` on the main thread, I'd also recommend moving its creation to the background thread too.

```
let schoolRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: school)

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm!

        let person = new Person()
        person.name = "John"
        person.school = realm.resolve(schoolRef)!

        try realm.write {
            realm.add(person, update: true)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Success!
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Error!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. One of the mistakes I was making was creating Person on the main thread, as you pointed out. Cheers!

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help! :)

Comment: I feel that Realm could do with a better documentation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all of that information I listed there is in the Realm documentation now. :)